# Calculator with specific methods only. Normal and recursive

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration, calculator

So atm im stuck with my calculator. It is only allowed to use following methods:

```
int succ(int x){
    return ++x;
}



int neg(int x){
    return -x;
}
```

What i already got is +, -. *. Iterativ an also recursive (so i can also use them if needed).
Now im stuck on the divide method because i dont know how to deal with the commas and the logic behind it. Just to imagine what it looks like to deal with succ() and neg() heres an example of an subtraction iterativ and recursive:

```
int sub(int x, int y){
    if (y > 0){
        y = neg(y);
        x = add(x, y);
        return x;
    }
    else if (y < 0){
        y = neg(y);
        x = add(x, y);
        return x;
    }
    else if (y == 0) {
        return x;
    }
   }

int sub_recc(int x, int y){
    if (y < 0){
        y = neg(y);
        x = add_recc(x, y);
        return x;
    } else if (y > 0){
        x = sub_recc(x, y - 1); 
        x = x - 1;
        return x;
    }else if( y == 0) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: can your calculator only operate on type `int`? Because if so, you won't need to worry about commas, as `int`s can only store whole numbers, so `7/3==2` for example.

Comment: Sadly int is not my final version. :D im supposed to use float with commas and all that stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can substract and add, then you can handle integer division. In pseudo code it is just:

```
division y/x is:
   First handle signs because we will only divide positive integers
   set sign = 0
   if y > 0 then y = neg(y), sign = 1 - sign
   if x > 0 then y = neg(y), sign = 1 - sign
   ok, if sign is 0 nothing to do, if sign is 1, we will negate the result

   Now the quotient is just the number of times you can substract the divisor:
   set quotient = 0
   while y > x do
       y = y - x
       quotient = quotient + 1
   Ok we have the absolute value of the quotient, now for the sign:
   if sign == 1, then quotient = neg(quotient)
```

The correct translation in C++ language as well as the recursive part are left as an exercise...

Hint for recursion y/x == 1 + (y-x)/x while y>x

---

Above was the integer part. Integer is nice and easy because it gives exact operations. A floating point representation in a *base* is always something close to mantissa * base<sup>exp</sup> where mantissa is either an integer number with a maximum number of digits or a number between 0 and 1 (said normal representation). And you can pass from one representation to the other but changing the exponent part by the number of digits of the mantissa: 2.5 is 25 10<sup>-1</sup> (int mantissa) of .25 10<sup>1</sup> (0 <= mantissa < 1).

So if you want to operate base 10 floating point numbers you should:

- convert an integer to a floating point (mantissa + exponent) representation
- for addition and substraction, the result exponent is *a priori*  the greater of the exponents. Both mantissa shall be scaled to that exponent and added/substracted. Then the final exponent must be adjusted because the operation may have added an additional digit (7 + 9 = 16) or have caused the highest order ones to vanish (101 - 98 - 3)
- for product, you add the exponents and multiply the mantissas, and then *normalize* (adjust exponent) the resul
- for division, you scale the mantissa by the maximum number of digits, make the division with the integer division algorithm, and again normalise. For example 1/3 with a precision of 6 digits is obtained with:
  1/3 = (1 * 10<sup>6</sup> /3) * 10<sup>-6</sup> = (1000000/3) * 10<sup>-6</sup>

it give 333333 * 10<sup>-6</sup> so .333333 in normalized form

Ok, it will be a lot of boiling plate code, but nothing really hard.

Log story made short: just remember how you learned that with a paper and a pencil...

Comment: That already helped alot. But the main problem where my brain shuts down ist for example when i devide 6 by 5. 6 / 5 = 1,2. How am i supposed to get the ,2 in there. Theres no way for my brain to go through the while loop like 0,2 times ':D

Comment: @JanFischer Hint: there are ten `0.1`s in `1`, ten `0.01`s in `0.1`, ...